# error C2679 binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'T' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++

Hi im new to c++ and I'm getting this error in my program

```
   Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'T' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

I think the error is coming from my pop() function but I don't have any idea how to fix it. I've pointed out the line with the error with an arrow which is close  to the bottom. Can someone please guide me on how to fix this error much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Queue.h"
#include "Queue.h"
#include "UniqueQueue.h"
#include "UniqueQueue.h"
#include "Dictionary.h"
#include "Dictionary.h"



int cout = 0; // won't compile if headers don't follow convention

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "Command Line:\n";
    std::cout << "--------------------------\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        std::cout << std::setw(3) << i + 1 << ": " << argv[i] << '\n';
    std::cout << "--------------------------\n\n";

    // Data to be used by the template classes
    long   dataSetA[]{ 22, 1, 455, 90, 455, 6, 43 };
    double dataSetB[]{ 34.556, 3333.3303, 122.55, 3333.3333, 678.54, 3333.3389 };
    sdds::Dictionary pData[]{
        sdds::Dictionary("dome", "a rounded vault forming the roof of a building or structure."),
        sdds::Dictionary("pollution", "An introduction into the environment of a substance that has harmful effect"),
        sdds::Dictionary("slide", "a structure with a smooth sloping surface for children to slide down."),
        sdds::Dictionary("complete", "having all the necessary or appropriate parts"),
        sdds::Dictionary("pollution", "An introduction into the environment of a substance that has harmful effect"),
        sdds::Dictionary("slide", "a structure with a smooth sloping surface for children to slide down."),
        sdds::Dictionary("complete", "having all the necessary or appropriate parts"),
        sdds::Dictionary("acceptable", "able to be agreed on; suitable"),
        sdds::Dictionary("dome", "a rounded vault forming the roof of a building or structure.")
    };

    

    {
        std::cout << "******************************************************\n";
        std::cout << "* Testing the UniqueQueue of Pairs                   *\n";
        std::cout << "******************************************************\n";
        sdds::Queue<sdds::Dictionary, 100>* UniqueQueueDictionary = new sdds::UniqueQueue<sdds::Dictionary>();

        for (const auto& item : pData)
            UniqueQueueDictionary->push(item);

        std::cout << "UniqueQueueue size: [" << UniqueQueueDictionary->size() << "]\n";
        UniqueQueueDictionary->display();

        std::cout << "Item [1]: [" << (*UniqueQueueDictionary)[1].getTerm() << "]["
            << (*UniqueQueueDictionary)[1].getDefinition() << "]\n";
        std::cout << "Item [4]: [" << (*UniqueQueueDictionary)[4].getTerm() << "]["
            << (*UniqueQueueDictionary)[4].getDefinition() << "]\n";
        std::cout << "Item [11]: [" << (*UniqueQueueDictionary)[11].getTerm() << "]["
            << (*UniqueQueueDictionary)[11].getDefinition() << "]\n";

        std::cout << "----------------------\n";
        std::cout << "| Testing Pop        |\n";
        std::cout << "----------------------\n\n";

        std::cout << "Popped Item: " << UniqueQueueDictionary->pop() << std::endl; --> Error line
        std::cout << "----------------------\n";
        UniqueQueueDictionary->display();


        std::cout << "******************************************************\n\n";
        delete UniqueQueueDictionary;
    }

    return cout;
}
```

Queue.h file

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H_
#define QUEUE_H_
#include "Dictionary.h"

namespace sdds
{
    template <typename T, unsigned int CAPACITY>
    class Queue
    {
        T m_item[CAPACITY]{};
        unsigned int m_size{};
        T dummy{};

    public:
        Queue()
        {

        };
        T pop()
        {
            if (m_size > 0)
            {
                T temp = m_item[0];
                for (size_t i = 0; i < m_size - 1; i++)
                {
                    m_item[i] = m_item[i + 1];
                }
                m_size--;
                return temp;
            }
            return dummy;
        }
        size_t size()
        {
            return m_size;
        };
        std::ostream& display(std::ostream& ostr = std::cout)
        {
            ostr << "----------------------" << std::endl;
            ostr << "| Dictionary Content |" << std::endl;
            ostr << "----------------------" << std::endl;
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_size; i++) {
                ostr << m_item[i] << std::endl;
            }
            ostr << "----------------------" << std::endl;
            return ostr;
        }
         virtual bool push(const T& item)
        {
            bool suc = false;
            if (m_size < CAPACITY)
            {
                m_item[m_size] = item;
                m_size++;
                suc = true;
            }
            return suc;
        };

        

       virtual T& operator[](size_t index)
        {
            if (index >= 0 && index < CAPACITY)
            {
                return m_item[index];
            }
            return dummy;
        }
       virtual ~Queue()
       {
       }
    };
    template <>
    Queue<Dictionary, 100u>::Queue()
    {
        Dictionary a("Empty Term", "Empty Substitute");
        dummy = a;
    };

}
#endif
```

dictionary.h

```
#ifndef DICTIONARY_H_
#define DICTIONARY_H_

#include <string>
namespace sdds
{
    class Dictionary
    {
        std::string m_term{};
        std::string m_definition{};
    public:
        const std::string& getTerm() const
        {
            return m_term;
        }
        const std::string& getDefinition() const
        {
            return m_definition;
        }
        Dictionary(const std::string& term, const std::string& definition) : m_term{ term }, m_definition{ definition }{}

        // TODO: Code the missing prototype functions and operators
        //       that the class needs in order to work with the Queue class.
        //       Implement them in the Dictionary.cpp file.
        const std::string& getTermConst()const
        {
            return m_term;
        }

        Dictionary() : m_term{ "" }, m_definition{ "" }{};
        std::ostream& display(std::ostream& ostr = std::cout);

       
    };
    bool operator==(const Dictionary& lhs, const Dictionary& rhs);

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, Dictionary& D);
}
#endif
```

Comment: Why are you including headers multiple times?

Comment: thats how my professor wrote it

Comment: Why are you using a pointer and dynamically allocating an object for your UniqueQueueDictionary? There seems to be no justification for that in this code. Using a local variable for it would be more appropriate in these circumstances.

Comment: thats what my prof gave me. Im not allowed to modify that code

Comment: There is no `operator <<` for `sdds::Dictionary`.

Comment: I missed the line you marked earlier. Re that line, what does `UniqueQueueDictionary->pop()` return? Combine that with @molbdnilo's comment.

Comment: I don't see Dictionary.h, so don't know how the class is defined. `UniqueQueueDictionary->pop()` returns a Dictionary object. My best guess is `operator <<` is not defined in class `Dictionary`, so can not be used in `std::cout <<` statement.

Comment: just added the dictionary.h file

Comment: What OS do you use? What compiler did you use? What's the version of the compiler? I see `operator <<` is defined in `dictionary.h`, not sure why it does not work. Is the `operator <<` implemented in `dictionary.cpp`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the definition of  `operator <<` in `dictionary.h`

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, Dictionary& D);
```

The `operator <<` requires its operands will not be changed. Make sure to add `const` keyword if you pass argument by reference.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, const Dictionary& D);
```

Or simply pass argument by value, like

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, Dictionary D);
```

Here are the codes I tested:

main.cpp (tested with `new` and local variable, both work)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "queue.h"
#include "dictionary.h"

int cout = 0; // won't compile if headers don't follow convention

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "Command Line:\n";
    std::cout << "--------------------------\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        std::cout << std::setw(3) << i + 1 << ": " << argv[i] << '\n';
    std::cout << "--------------------------\n\n";

    // Data to be used by the template classes
    long   dataSetA[]{ 22, 1, 455, 90, 455, 6, 43 };
    double dataSetB[]{ 34.556, 3333.3303, 122.55, 3333.3333, 678.54, 3333.3389 };
    sdds::Dictionary pData[]{
        sdds::Dictionary("dome", "a rounded vault forming the roof of a building or structure."),
        sdds::Dictionary("pollution", "An introduction into the environment of a substance that has harmful effect"),
        sdds::Dictionary("slide", "a structure with a smooth sloping surface for children to slide down."),
        sdds::Dictionary("complete", "having all the necessary or appropriate parts"),
        sdds::Dictionary("pollution", "An introduction into the environment of a substance that has harmful effect"),
        sdds::Dictionary("slide", "a structure with a smooth sloping surface for children to slide down."),
        sdds::Dictionary("complete", "having all the necessary or appropriate parts"),
        sdds::Dictionary("acceptable", "able to be agreed on; suitable"),
        sdds::Dictionary("dome", "a rounded vault forming the roof of a building or structure.")
    };

    {
        std::cout << "******************************************************\n";
        std::cout << "* Testing the UniqueQueue of Pairs                   *\n";
        std::cout << "******************************************************\n";
        sdds::Queue<sdds::Dictionary, 100>* UniqueQueueDictionary = new sdds::Queue<sdds::Dictionary, 100>();

        for (const auto& item : pData)
            UniqueQueueDictionary->push(item);

        std::cout << "UniqueQueueue size: [" << UniqueQueueDictionary->size() << "]\n";
        UniqueQueueDictionary->display();

        std::cout << "Item [1]: [" << (*UniqueQueueDictionary)[1].getTerm() << "]["
        << (*UniqueQueueDictionary)[1].getDefinition() << "]\n";
        std::cout << "Item [4]: [" << (*UniqueQueueDictionary)[4].getTerm() << "]["
        << (*UniqueQueueDictionary)[4].getDefinition() << "]\n";
        std::cout << "Item [11]: [" << (*UniqueQueueDictionary)[11].getTerm() << "]["
        << (*UniqueQueueDictionary)[11].getDefinition() << "]\n";

        std::cout << "----------------------\n";
        std::cout << "| Testing Pop        |\n";
        std::cout << "----------------------\n\n";

        std::cout << "Popped Item: " << UniqueQueueDictionary->pop() << std::endl;// --> Error line
        std::cout << "----------------------\n";
        UniqueQueueDictionary->display();


        sdds::Queue<sdds::Dictionary, 100> qd;

        for (const auto& item : pData)
            qd.push(item);

        std::cout << "UniqueQueueue size: [" << qd.size() << "]\n";
        qd.display();

        std::cout << "Item [1]: [" << qd[1].getTerm() << "]["
        << qd[1].getDefinition() << "]\n";
        std::cout << "Item [4]: [" << qd[4].getTerm() << "]["
        << qd[4].getDefinition() << "]\n";
        std::cout << "Item [11]: [" << qd[11].getTerm() << "]["
        << qd[11].getDefinition() << "]\n";

        std::cout << "----------------------\n";
        std::cout << "| Testing Pop        |\n";
        std::cout << "----------------------\n\n";

        std::cout << "Popped Item: " << qd.pop() << std::endl;// --> Error line
        std::cout << "----------------------\n";
        qd.display();


        std::cout << "******************************************************\n\n";
        delete UniqueQueueDictionary;
    }

    return cout;
}
```

queue.h

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H_
#define QUEUE_H_
#include "dictionary.h"

namespace sdds
{
    template <typename T, unsigned int CAPACITY>
    class Queue
    {
/*        // the following 3 lines wont compile with gcc-4.8.5 or ealier, but copile with gcc-7.1.0
        T m_item[CAPACITY]{};
        unsigned int m_size{};
        T dummy{};
*/
        // the following 3 lines will compile with gcc-4.8.5 or gcc-4.4.7
        T m_item[CAPACITY];
        unsigned int m_size;
        T dummy;

    public:
        Queue()
        {
            m_size = 0; // need to initialize for older gcc compiler
        };
        T pop()
        {
            if (m_size > 0)
            {
                T temp = m_item[0];
                for (size_t i = 0; i < m_size - 1; i++)
                {
                    m_item[i] = m_item[i + 1];
                }
                m_size--;
                return temp;
            }
            return dummy;
        }
        size_t size()
        {
            return m_size;
        };
        std::ostream& display(std::ostream& ostr = std::cout)
        {
            ostr << "----------------------" << std::endl;
            ostr << "| Dictionary Content |" << std::endl;
            ostr << "----------------------" << std::endl;
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_size; i++) {
                ostr << m_item[i] << std::endl;
            }
            ostr << "----------------------" << std::endl;
            return ostr;
        }
        virtual bool push(const T& item)
        {
            bool suc = false;
            if (m_size < CAPACITY)
            {
                m_item[m_size] = item;
                m_size++;
                suc = true;
            }
            return suc;
        };

    

       virtual T& operator[](size_t index)
       {
           if (index >= 0 && index < CAPACITY)
           {
               return m_item[index];
           }
           return dummy;
       }
       virtual ~Queue()
       {
       }
    };
    template <>
    Queue<Dictionary, 100u>::Queue()
    {
        Dictionary a;
        dummy = a;
        m_size = 0;      // need to initialize for older gcc compiler
    };

}
#endif
```

dictionary.h

```
#ifndef DICTIONARY_H_
#define DICTIONARY_H_

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
namespace sdds
{
    class Dictionary
    {
        std::string m_term{};
        std::string m_definition{};
    public:
        const std::string& getTerm() const
        {
            return m_term;
        }
        const std::string& getDefinition() const
        {
            return m_definition;
        }
        Dictionary(const std::string& term, const std::string& definition) : m_term{ term }, m_definition{ definition }{}

        // TODO: Code the missing prototype functions and operators
        //       that the class needs in order to work with the Queue class.
        //       Implement them in the Dictionary.cpp file.
        const std::string& getTermConst() const
        {
            return m_term;
        }

        Dictionary() : m_term{ "" }, m_definition{ "" }{};
        std::ostream& display(std::ostream& ostr = std::cout);
   
        Dictionary& operator=(const Dictionary& d);
        bool operator==(const Dictionary& d);
    };
    bool operator==(const Dictionary& lhs, const Dictionary& rhs);
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, Dictionary D);
//    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, const 
Dictionary& D);
}

#endif
```

dictionary.cpp

```
#include "dictionary.h"
#include <iostream>

std::ostream& sdds::Dictionary::display(std::ostream& ostr) {

   return ostr << *this;
}

// Assignment operator
sdds::Dictionary& sdds::Dictionary::operator=(const 
sdds::Dictionary& r) {
    this->m_term = r.getTerm();
    this->m_definition = r.getDefinition();
    return *this;
}

// Comparison operator
bool sdds::Dictionary::operator==(const sdds::Dictionary& d) {
    return m_term.compare(d.getTerm())==0 && m_definition.compare(d.getDefinition())==0;
}

// Comparison operator - outside the class, but in the namespace
bool sdds::operator==(const sdds::Dictionary& l, const sdds::Dictionary& r) {
    return l.getTerm().compare(r.getTerm())==0 && l.getDefinition().compare(r.getDefinition())==0;
}

/** define the << operator inside the namespace - works (passes D as value will not change it in the caller) */
std::ostream& sdds::operator<<(std::ostream&ostr, sdds::Dictionary D) {
    ostr << "[" << D.getTerm() << "][" << D.getDefinition() << "]";
    return ostr;
}

/** define the << operator inside the namespace - works (passes D as reference, make sure to add const.)
std::ostream& sdds::operator<<(std::ostream&ostr, const sdds::Dictionary& D) {
    ostr << "[" << D.getTerm() << "][" << D.getDefinition() << "]";
    return ostr;
}
*/

/** define the << operator out of the namespace - works
std::ostream&operator<<(std::ostream&ostr, const sdds::Dictionary& D) {
    ostr << "[" << D.getTerm() << "][" << D.getDefinition() << "]";
    return ostr;
}
*/
```

Codes compiled with gcc-4.8.5 and later, but failed with gcc-4.4.7

```
g++ -std=c++0x -o main.e main.cpp dictionary.cpp
```

The ouput
[image]